# add_rewrite_endpoint not working

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I've been having looot of troubles with this function, I don't know what to do, because I tried everything.

I have a custom post type, let's call it study. The url structure for it is

```
http://example.com/study/studyname
```

They have different sections, I want to have the new structure like this:

```
http://example.com.com/study/studyname/view/view_arg
```

So far I've tried `add_rewrite_endpoint()` and `add_rewrite_rule()` functions, with any result.

I also tried to disable all my plugins just in case one of them may be the reason, but still fails. This is my code, I tried both options separately:

```
add_filter('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_endpoint('view', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES, 'view' );
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Here I also test it with `EP_ALL`, without the `view`, without flushing rules...

Also I tried to manually create the rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'study/([^/]+)/view/([^/]+)?$',
    'index.php?study=$matches[1]&view=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

And I read that the query_var should be used configured as well, so I did:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'conf_query_vars' );
function conf_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'view';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

I'm going to kill myself, if I try the url with the parameter itself (something like `http://example.com/study/studyname/?view=view_args`) it works like a charm, but I don't want to show this structure.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You get a 404?

Comment: »I'm going to kill myself«...don't do that

Comment: Yes, the error is a 404. And the kill myself was just and expression xD

Comment: Not seen anyone else mention this, so are you updating the Permalinks again after a code update? I did some rewrite changes before which didn't work until I went into Permalinks and clicked Save Changes.

Comment: What do you want this endpoint to do? You're not using doing anything with it, it seems? Try adding an action for `template_include`. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should (and does from quick check) work in principle. You should **not** be flushing permalink every page load, just once.

Use rewrite helper like [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to see if rules are being generated, what they are, and how are they matching to real URLs in your site.

Comment: I know, and I don't understand why. Maybe I'll use that tool you told me just to know it, I gave up because I spent a loot of hours with this and I decided that it didn't worth the time any more, so I make a turnaround with this. Still, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but that may help someone, and also give an answer to that old question.
I've created a plugin that was creating two new endpoints. `endpoint_a` and `endpoint_b`.

The `endpoint_b` was just a copy of the `endpoint_a` and was imported into the same plugin.
they also both had they own `add_action('init')` function.

What I've did to make the `endpointB` works was as follows:

1. use a single `add_action('init')` function for the both endpoints

```php
 add_action('init', function () {
  add_rewrite_endpoint('endpoint_a', EP_PAGES);
  add_rewrite_endpoint('endpoint_b', EP_PAGES);
});
```

2. deactivate the plugin, and reactivate it (wasn't working without this step)

So, you may had somehow the same problem.
I hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

I just similarly struggled with this, and I almost gave up as well. Join me on my journey of discovery! (Or just skip to **The Solution**)

---

**The Problem:**

Usually, when you create a new endpoint, you can fix it not working by simply going to the Permalinks page under Settings > Permalinks and just saving the permalink settings. This, somewhere in the WP code, must call `flush_rewrite_rules()`. This feels gross to me, because if your plugin will be used by more than one person (you) or used by non-PHP devs in general, they won't know to go save the Permalink rules after activating your plugin. Your plugin should be ready to go after activation without some strange arcane second step necessary.

WordPress seems to need you to `add_rewrite_rule()` on `init` every page load, HOWEVER, you also need to then `flush_rewrite_rules()` after you initially add the rewrite rule... BUT, as @Rarst says, you should NOT `flush_rewrite_rules()` on every page `init`.

---

**The Solution:**

So, I came up with this technique, and tested it. This technique does not require using set_transient, although you could easily use it as others have.

**First**, you want your plugin to have an activator. Whether it's a Class or just a function, you should have a function that is called upon activation of your plugin:

(replace generic variables, classes and function names accordingly)

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate' );

function activate() {
    //this function will be called at activation, and then on every init as well:
    Plugin_Class_Public::add_endpoint();

    //run this at activation ONLY, AFTER setting the endpoint - needed for your endpoint to actually create a query_vars entry:
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Here is the function to add the endpoint:

```
public static function add_endpoint() {
    //be sure to replace your_endpoint_slug with your own endpoint
    add_rewrite_endpoint('your_endpoint_slug', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES); 
}
```

Then, register your endpoint on init by calling the function above:

```
add_action('init', array('Plugin_Class_Public', 'add_endpoint'));
```

And be sure to set a hook for template_include:

```
add_action('template_include', array('Plugin_Class_Public', 'endpoint_output'));
```

Which will call a function that looks like this:

```
public static function endpoint_output($template) {
    if(!is_home()){  //we probably don't want this to run on our homepage
        global $wp;
        global $wp_query;
        
        $output = "";
        
        /*note: your_endpoint_slug needs to be replaced here as you did above. 
          Its value will be set to whatever comes after it in the url,
          eg: www.website.com/your_endpoint_slug/some_more/url -
          $wp_query->query_vars['your_endpoint_slug'] = "some_more/url"
         */
        if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['your_endpoint_slug'])) {
            $output = Plugin_Class_Public::generate_output(wp_query->query_vars['your_endpoint_slug']);
            echo $output;
            exit;               
        }
        //print output
    }
    //nothing matched our endpoint, or it's the homepage:
    return $template;
}
```

This function builds your output:

```
public static function generate_output($url_after_endpoint_in_url) {        
    $output = "";
    //do something to generate your desired output and return it
    return $output;
}
```

You can also unregister your endpoint on deactivation by calling flush_rewrite_rules(), to be a bit more tidy, although this doesn't seem to work properly, as the init() function above runs when you deactivate as well- so it's still saving that endpoint. Open to suggestions on how to fix this. Though, once the plugin is deactivated, it won't run the function from template_include anymore, so no real harm done, IMO. You can always save your permalinks to remove this extraneous query_var later.

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate' );

function deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

(Note on register_activation/deactivation_hook functions: The first parameter in each of these functions refers to your main plugin file, which is the file in which you have placed the plugin header comment. Usually these two functions will be triggered from within the main plugin file; however, if the functions are placed in any other file, you must update the first parameter to correctly point to the main plugin file.)